# Interpolation on excel

Tags: math, matrix, interpolation

I've a source data like this:

```
       35    40
-15    15.0  15.1
-10    17.2  17.4
-5     19.7  19.8
```

and I need to find the value in (-16, 37). I've tried with linear interpolation but I can solve only with (x,y) couple of values. Could you help me?

thanks a lot,
Andrea

Comment: I've tried using Ax=b solution for Vandermonde matrix to calculate coefficient of polynom, but I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: could you explain the "source data" a little? I've attended some linear algebra courses at uni - but I cannot really "understand" the format of your data....

Comment: on x there are externale temperature and un y there are the output water. Point (x,y) are the kW necessary to heat water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all, your suggests has been very helpful for me to understand better the problem.

In the beginning I've putted the problem in a wrong way because I've take cue from the graphical representation of the data, a matrix. But, after some "mumble" :) I've understand that the correct way to represent the problem was:

f(x1,x2) = y

```
       35    40
-15    15.0  15.1
-10    17.2  17.4
-5     19.7  19.8
```

so, i.e. f(35, -15) = 15.0

To obtain value in x1 = 37 and x2 = -13 I can use bilinear interpolation.
The graphical representation of the problem in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bilinear_interpolation.png

was my flash of inspiration.

Thanks to all!

Andrea

Comment: If anyone is looking for Excel code for bilinear interpolation, I have written a module for this: https://github.com/DanGolding/Linear-and-bilinear-interpolation-in-Excel

Answer (score 6):

You could try to fit a plane to your data:

```
z=A*x+B*y+C
```

Then solve for A,B,C using least-squares and the 6 points (-15,35,15.0),...
Excel may be able to find the optimal values for you.

**Edit**

Here I inserted your data (the green cells), and used the solver tool to build the optimal linear model z=A*x+B*y+C. (x is 35,40 and y is -15,-10,-5).  A,B,C are the blue cells on the left.  Then the pink cells are A*x+B*y+C, and the red cells are (date-model)^2.  The error is the sum of all these 6 red cells.

Then use the Solver tool (needs to be activated from Excel options). Define the error cell as target (minimize) and A,B,C as variable cells. It will find the best A,B,C values.

These values are then applied to your request (x=37 and y=-16), giving the result 14.5.

Comment: This is a good answer, especially if 6 pts is all Andrea has.

Comment: You're image link went stale, removed.

Answer (score 2):

Andrea, it looks as if the people trying to help (including me) are still having difficulty with your data.

To do anything with a matrix in excel, you need to use array formulas.  When you've finished typing in the formula, don't press Enter. Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead. If you've done it right, you'll see the formula you entered surrounded by {}'s in the formula bar.

If you think your data is linear, and you want to try the approach identified by @tom10, try

```
=TREND(<known y's>,<known x's>,<new x's>)
```

Which will return an array of new y's for each new x provided.

You also might try matrix formulas.  If you can express your problem as a system of linear equations, excel has a few matrix formulas. There's a good walkthrough [here](http://www.dslimited.biz/excel_tutorials/simultaneouslinearequations.html).  These are only going to help you if your matrices are square.

Answer (score 1):

Linear interpolation will find entries inside the limits given. ie -5 >= x >= -15. 
To find value for -16 you will need to extrapolate.

One way is fitting fitting a surface to the points e.g solving Ax = b) or saying it is the same as (-15, 37) - so depends on your needs and choosing the correct method which is not really what this site is about.

If you know the method we can tell you how to calculate it but you should show what you have tried by showing your code.

Comment: my fault, the vaule coul be inside the limit, ie (-13, 37). 
I need to use excel because it's the requirement. I've tried to calculate the polinom using the Vandermonde matrix. For first I'm trying to calculate this:

1 -15 15 a0 35
1 -10 17.4 a1 40

but the problem is that this method, if I remember well, works only for square matrix.

Comment: matrix is [1 -15 15; 1 -10 17.4] [a0 a1] = [35; 40]

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on what you do a quick look in a numerical analysis book for > one dimensional interpolation suggests bicubic interpolation or splines, so I think you need to give more information on the problem and method you have to use to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a reasonable estimate by treating this is three independent linear problems:

1. At a constant x-value (say, 35), use a linear fit to the 1D data to find the z-value at your target y-value (-16), using the three y-values and three z-values.  Call this Z<sub>0</sub>.
2. As 1. but now for the other x-value (40).  Call this Z<sub>1</sub>.
3. Now do a fit in the other direciton... at y=-16, use (35, Z<sub>0</sub>), and (40, Z<sub>1</sub>) to find the Z-value at the target x-value.

This is an approximation and not the best solution, but I doubt Excel does the multivariate analysis that you would need to solve the problem correctly -- where you would fit a surface to these points.  I don't know Excel well though, and could be doubting it out of ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Andrea, if you want to use piecewise bilinear interpolation in 2D in Excel, can I recommend the VBA function [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/interpolation/#Two_dimensional_interpolation_). That's worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The Interp2dTab function of [xongrid](http://xongrid.sourceforge.net/) can be used for bilinear interpolation